Swiper Js Loop not working slideToLoop and loop true
When there is slideperview and loop true swiper .js not work properly any idea how to fix it
swiper.slider(loop, slideby=4)
Need to know why it's not working when there slideToLoop to 0 moves only one slide why..
There are some loopedlength
